# Missing Web Part or List View Tools Tabs in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to learn how to export a web part with SharePoint Designer 2013.
I created a document library and added a new view with a style other than default. I refreshed SharePoint Designer to make this update.

I opened the site and selected the new view to open. A box came up and told me that there were no regions that are editable in safe mode, and asked me if I want to open the page in advanced mode. I click Yes.

I find the WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart tag and click on it...nothing happens. I right click on it and select "Tag Properties" and the "Page Properties" dialog box opens up. I can't even see the tag displayed at the bottom right of the page.

[image: Opened View]

[image: Page Properties box]

Everything I read says that this is a common issue with SharePoint Designer 2013, but not even their solutions are working with my program. HELP!